# Como usar Template em C++?

Tags: c++, template

Estou aprendendo um pouco sobre template e fiz um exemplo, mas quando fui aplicar ao meu projeto não consegui, vamos ao seguinte teste:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class p{
public:
     Type setVal(Type i){return i*i;};
private:
    Type dado;
};

int main(){
    p<int> obj;
    p<double> obj2;
    cout << " RESULTADO COM INT "  << obj.setVal(8);
    cout << " RESULTADO COM DOUBLE "  << obj2.setVal(7.4);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Neste código eu estou criando uma classe `p` e nela estou colocando um template `Type` para o retorno dela e para o parâmetro dela, abaixo eu instancio dois objetos da classe passando o tipo de cada uma e obtenho o resultado esperado, cada um dos objetos recebe o valor referente ao seu tipo.

Agora vamos para as seguintes dúvidas

1 - Como eu implemento o metodo fora da classe? 
exemplo:

```
Type p::setVal(Type i){
    // code goes here
}
```

2 - (preciso entender o 1 antes de fazer o 2) adaptar a classe Node/Pilha para
 ser genérica

```
class No{
public:
    char exp;
    No* prox;
    No(){prox = NULL;}
};


class pilha{
    public:
        pilha();
        void push(char expressao);
        char pop();
        char getTop();
        bool isEmpty();
        bool clear();
        void print();
    private:
    No* topo;
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para definir os métodos você precisa dizer que está usando `template` ali também. Cada parte é independente:

```
template <class Type>
Type p<Type>::setVal(Type i){
    // code goes here
}
```

Aí pode aplicar na sua classe exemplo sem muito segredo. Talvez você esteja achando que uma classe precise ser tratada de forma especial dentro da outra, mas não tem nada especial, quando você for instanciar uma classe como membro dentro da outra classe, é só usar o tipo parametrizado, tudo será substituído adequadamente pelo compilador:

```
template <class Type>
class No<Type> {
public:
    Type exp;
    No<Type>* prox;
    No<Type>(){prox = NULL;}
};

template <class Type>
class pilha<Type> {
    public:
        pilha();
        void push(Type expressao);
        Type pop();
        Type getTop();
        bool isEmpty();
        bool clear();
        void print();
    private:
    No<Type>* topo; //aqui deve ser sua dúvida, tem que instanciar parametrizado
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Template/Example.cpp).

Note que da mesma forma que eu disse antes que cada parte é independente, aqui vale também. Então o uso do `Type` na classe do nó e na classe da pilha (isto está esquisito, pilha não deveria ter nó) é pura coincidência, não há relação entre eles. Isto não é uma variável com tempo de vida em todo o código. É um [*placeholder*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_text) com tempo de vida dentro da área do `template` que acaba no fim de uma classe ou definição de método. Poderia usar qualquer palavra aí.

Comment: 1 teste, quando eu coloco o `template <class Type>` acima da classe e  abaixo da função do setVal() aparece a seguinte msg: `error: 'template<class Type> class p' used without template parameter`

Comment: código: https://ideone.com/uS4ufd

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues me desculpe, eu esqueci de parametrizar o método mesmo, acertei agora.

Comment: Consegui aplicar no meu projeto

Answer (score 1):

No C++ podemos usar template em:

- Funções
- Structs
- Classes

Eu não sei em questão de variáveis  e de funções lambdas, veja os exemplos:

```
//Devemos usar template antes da declaração.
//O mais comum em template é usar typename que é indefinido, mas pode usar class porém isso
//seria para trabalhar em classes. É colocado entre <>
template <typename I, typename O> O funcao (I valor){
   //Na função ambos podem usar template em parâmetros e retorno. Note que é como estivéssemos
   //declarando uma variável, só que é template.
}

template <class T> class MinhaClasse{
   //Na classe seria a mesma coisa em função, mas usamos em declaração e talvez pode usar em função.
   //Por exemplo estou criando a classe objeto em minha API, semelhante ao Java e C#, temos toString,
   //equals entre outros. Eu posso usar em herança só que na herança use a classe que está herdando
   //em template.
}

template <typename T1, class T2> struct MinhaStruct{
   //Mesma coisa da classe porém é melhor usar typename, algo que preferir.
}
```

As lambdas receberam grande mundança em C++20, podendo usar template mas isso é complicado.