# Função com template

Tags: c++

Pessoal alguém pode me ajudar.

Tenho que fazer a seguinte função abaixo.

> Elabora uma função para retornar o maior valor dentre dois números,
>   utilizando template.  
> A função deverá conter, no máximo, dois
>   parâmetros formais. 
> Os valores dos parâmetros reais (atuais) não
>   poderão ser alterados

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>

void maior(T *Param1 , T *Param2){

    T aux;

    if(Param1 >= Param2)

      aux = *Param1;

      else

      aux = *Param2;

};

int main()
{
    int aux;

    int num1 = 3 , num2 = 4;

    maior <int>(&num1 , &num2);

    cout<<"O maior valor é:"<< aux <<endl;
```

Não sei se é por este caminho.

Comment: Você não pôs retorno em `maior`, como também a comparação está errada

Comment: pode me explicar melhor estou estudando por conta própria, não entendo muito.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57790/64969

Comment: Eu procurei aqui no site por _template C++_ e veio muita coisa útil e bacana, talvez alguma das respostas resolva seu problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você ja deve saber, a forma de declarar funções com templates é:

```
template <class identificador> declaração_da_função;
```

Então, uma função que retorna o maior valor dentre dois valores pode ser definida da seguinte forma:

```
template <class T>
T GetMax (T a, T b) {
 return (a>b?a:b); //operador condicional ternário
}
```

Para usar uma função definida com template, basta usar uma sintaxe similar a esta:

```
declaração_da_função <tipo do dado> (parâmetros);
```

Então, um programa que usa o template acima pode ser escrito da seguinte forma:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
T GetMax (T a, T b) {
    return (a>b?a:b); //operador condicional ternário
}

int main()
{
    int num1 = 3 , num2 = 4;
    int maior = GetMax<int>(num1,num2);
    cout<<"O maior valor é:"<< maior <<endl;
}
```

[REFERENCIA](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/)

Comment: Tinha achado algo similar num livro aqui, estava pesquisando o que era o operador ternário.

Comment: @CarlosFerreira ouvi falar em ternário? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17398/64969

Comment: sim agora já sei o que è.

Comment: Não há a necessidade de se usar como `GetMax<int>(num1, num2);`. Pode-se usar como uma chamada de função normal, tipo: `GetMax(num1, num2);`. O compilador faz a dedução do tipo automaticamente